# Casting derived type to base type - Not using base method implementation

Tags: c#, casting

Could somebody please explain why when I cast my derived type to its base type, the base types implementation of a virtual method is not used.

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, i'm an employee");
    }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public override void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, i'm a manager");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    Employee employee = (Employee)manager;

    employee.Introduce();   
}

// output is: Hello, i'm a manager
```

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what `virtual` means.

Comment: That's the nature of polymorphism.

Comment: To get the functionality you're expecting don't make the method `virtual` in the base class and then hide the method in the derived class by marking it as `new` instead of `override`.  Though that's typically not desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I just had some difficulty getting my head around the idea that casting a derived type to it's base didn't change it's type. So when I cast my manager object to Employee and used 'GetType()' it was still Manager.

Comment: The variable is typed as `Employee`, but it points to an instance of `Manager`, which happens to also be an `Employee` because of inheritance (that's why the assignment is valid).

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this: You have a list of employees (i.e. of base type). You can add objects of base type or derived types (e.g. managers) to this list. Now, you want to loop through this list:

```
foreach (Employee emp in list)
{
    emp.Introduce();
}
```

The loop variable casts all objects in the list to `Employee`. Here, casting does not change the type of the objects. It only changes the way you look at them. I.e. if managers had additional properties and methods, you would not see them through `emp`, but managers still behave like managers. And this is exactly what you are expecting: you want managers to introduce themselves as managers and employees to introduce themselves as employees.

This behavior is called [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).